# Probability Mass Function Numerical Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

For what values of $\alpha$ and $p$ the following PMF is a valid PMF?
$P_X(x) = (\alpha p)^x$
for $x = 2, 3, \ldots$
NOTE: $x$ is a power of $\alpha p$

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: I re-formatted your Question. Please check that it still says what you intended.

Comment: Hint: You want to find $b$ such that $b^2 + b^3 + b^4 + \cdots = 1.$ Then any $\alpha$ and $p$ with $b = \alpha p$ will be OK. Do you know how to sum a geometric series? Google if not.

Comment: Ok but I am little confuse here

Comment: I know geometric mean.. but what is 'b' here. It is not in question statement.

Comment: Ok Thanks @BruceEt . I have done this question. Thanks a lot for giving me hint of geometric series. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you got it.